# PowerShell (Eventlogs: How to compare dates/time?)

Tags: powershell, event-log

Till now I never used PowerShell, but now I have to. (Don’t worry I know how to program in other languages.)

What I have to do:

There are 2 eventlogs:
“EventID equals 3317 and Event Level equals Error" and "EventID equals 3317 and Event Level equals Information"

If there is an event with the level “Error” without an event with the level “Information” afterwards, then the output has to be “Critical”.
If there is an event with the level “Information” after this event with the level “Error” the output has to be “Ok”.
(If there is no event with that ID everything is "Ok".)

Now the problem is that I don’t know how to compare both date values I get from those lines...

```
get-eventlog -log application -EntryType error  –newest 1 | where {$_.eventID -eq 3317}
get-eventlog -log application -EntryType information  –newest 1 | where {$_.eventID -eq 3317}
```

Other solutions are appreciated as well. ;)

Greetings,
Cédric

**EDIT (The code):**

```
#Error:
$e_error = (get-eventlog -log application -EntryType error | where {$_.eventID -eq 3317} | Select -First 1).TimeGenerated
write-host "Error:       $e_error"

#Information:
$e_info = (get-eventlog -log application -EntryType information | where {$_.eventID -eq 3317} | Select -First 1).TimeGenerated
write-host "Information: $e_info"

if (($e_error) -and ($e_info)) {  #If $e_error (Error) & $e_info (Information) are not empty (events exists)
  $timediff = (new-timespan –start $e_error -end $e_info).TotalSeconds  #Difference
  if ($timediff -gt 0) {  #If $e_info (Information) newer than $e_error (Error)
    $res = "Ok"
  } else {  #If one of them or both are empty
    $res = "Critical"
  }
} else {
  if (($e_error) -and (!($e_info))) {  #If $e_error (Error) exists but not $e_info (Information)
    $res = "Critical"
  } else {  #If non of both or only Information exists
    $res = "Ok"
  }
}

write-host $res
```

Answer (score 0):

The TimeWritten or TimeGenerated values will give you dates and times to compare...

```
get-eventlog -log application -EntryType error  –newest 1 | where {$_.eventID -eq 3317} | Select TimeGenerated, TimeWritten
```

You can also do this to just pull that attribute

```
(get-eventlog -log application -EntryType error  –newest 1 | where {$_.eventID -eq 3317}).TimeGenerated
```

The other recommendation I'd make is to filter the events prior to selecting the last error. Otherwise you may miss an entry if another error occurs in quick succession. So the basis of your query should look like this:

```
get-eventlog -log application -EntryType error  | where {$_.eventID -eq 3317} |  | Select -First 1
```

Comment: Thanks!, I would vote up, but I don't have enough reputation. ;)